# Save answers from the inputs - php

Tags: php, html, post, get, request

I tried use $_POST, $_GET and $_REQUEST but none of them work. What should I use to save answers from the inputs?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> <title>Sign Up</title> </head> 
    <body> 
        <form method="POST"> 
            <input type="text" name="first" id='first'> 
            <input type="text" name='last' id='last'> 
            <button type='submit' name='submit'>Click</button> 
        </form> //WHERE THE INFORMATION IS ASKED 
        <?php //WHERE I ATTEMPT TO SAVE THE INFORMATION BUT I FAIL 
            include_once 'dbh.inc.php'; 
            $first = $_POST['first']; 
            $last = $_POST['last']; 
            /*Notice: Undefined index: first in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 14 Notice: Undefined index: last in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 15*/ 
            $sql = "INSERT INTO keep1(Firstname, Lastname) VALUES('$first', '$last');"; mysqli_query($conn, $sql); ?> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Snippet attached:

### ```html
 <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <title>Sign Up</title> </head> <body> <form method="POST"> <input type="text" name="first" id='first'> <input type="text" name='last' id='last'> <button type='submit' name='submit'>Click</button> </form> //WHERE THE INFORMATION IS ASKED <?php //WHERE I ATTEMPT TO SAVE THE INFORMATION BUT I FAIL include_once 'dbh.inc.php'; $first = $_POST['first']; $last = $_POST['last']; /*Notice: Undefined index: first in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 14 Notice: Undefined index: last in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 15*/ $sql = "INSERT INTO keep1(Firstname, Lastname) VALUES('$first', '$last');"; mysqli_query($conn, $sql); ?> </body> </html>
```

Comment: $_POST or $_REQUEST should work after submitting the form, but I imagine you'd be getting the undefined index errors before submitting the form since you aren't checking if it's a post request before accessing $_POST.

Comment: There seems to be no action specified in the form.

Answer (score 0):

You should take care of your code, make it easy to read. So the other people may read your code.

Try this, the error might appear because you haven't posted the data.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sign Up</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="first" id="first">
        <input type="text" name="last" id="last">
        <button type="submit">Click</button>
    </form>
<?php
include_once 'dbh.inc.php';
if(isset($_POST['first']) && isset($_POST['last'])){
    $first = $_POST['first'];
    $last = $_POST['last'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO keep1(Firstname, Lastname) VALUES('$first', '$last');";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```